# $f(z)$ goes to $\infty$ as $z$ goes to $z_0$, which is an isolated singularity. Show that $f(x)$ has a pole at $z_0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I guess I need to show that $z_0$ cannot be a removable singularity or an essential singularity.

For the case of removable singularity, can I prove it by this method: Since $z_0$ is removable, when $f(x)$ is expanded into Laurent expansion, only the analytic part ($k \ge 0$ ones) remains, so $f(x)$ cannot go to infinity as $z$ goes to $z_0$.

And I have no idea on how to prove $z_0$ cannot be an essential singularity.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: this is done in any book about complex analysis, e.g. rudin's Real and complex analysis

Comment: Take a look at Big Picard for the second part. It will give you a clear idea of how to approach it.

Comment: Is f given to be holomorphic in some neighbourhood around $z_{0}$?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem.